# webpage returns undefined when trying to load partial

Tags: c#, entity-framework, jquery, asp.net-mvc-partialview

What am I doing wrong with my partial view? I receive an "undefined" error from webpage when I click a student row. I tried "result" and "result.responseText" but it still alerts "undefined" Not sure why controller action returns error instead of success

here are my headers:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:54933/Base/ShowSpecificStudent
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:4
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:54933
Origin:http://localhost:54933
Referer:http://localhost:54933/base/ShowStudents
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.57 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
id:7
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Close
Content-Length:310
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 10 Sep 2013 21:24:24 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:2.0
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("tr[name='StudentTableRow']").click(showStudent);    
});

function showStudent() {    
var link = '/Base/ShowSpecificStudent';
var id = this.cells[0].innerText;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: link,
    data: { id: id },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#StudentDetail").html(result.responseText);
        //$("#StudentDetail").html(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert(result.message);
    }
});
```

Main View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<Student.Models.Student>>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/app/BaseScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Site.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th >
                ID
            </th>           
        </tr>

        <%if(Model != null) %>
    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr name="StudentTableRow">
            <td>
                <%: item.StudentID%>
            </td>            
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) %>
        <% { %>
        <div id ="StudentDetail">
  <%  Html.RenderPartial("ShowSpecificStudent", new List<Student.Models.Student>()); %> 
  </div>    
        <% } %> 

</body>
</html>
```

Partial View:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<div>
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Student Description
            </th>               
        </tr>
</table>
<table>
        <% if (Model != null) %>                   
         <%  foreach (var item in Model) { %>
         <tr>
            <td >
                <%: item.StudentDescription%>
            </td>      
        </tr> 
    <%}%>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller Action:

```
        [HttpPost()]
        public ActionResult ShowSpecificStudent(string id)
        {
            StudentEntities context = new StudentEntities();
            Int16 studentId = Convert.ToInt16(student);

            ViewData.Model = context.Students.Where(i => i.StudentID == studentId );
            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/ShowSpecificStudent.ascx", ViewData.Model);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, My data type in JS function was 'json' which should have been 'html'